# The_content is different from category archive to other pages

Tags: the-content

I'm trying to use a [plug-in](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpbookmark/) that is adding bookmark button to the posts.

It's working well except in the category archive page:

I can't figure out why `the_content()` on page, post and archives (tags, authors, and even search result) has the plugin div inside.. correctly.

But in the category archives there is not.

Any idea?

Comment: That depends A) on your theme (or to be more precise: the according archive template files) and B) on the plugin function itself. A wild guess: `the_content` is just not being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.
In the plugin file class-binnash-wpbookmark.php there is

```
if(is_category()) return $content;
```

I have just commented it and now I have the div at the top of The_Content() in the category archive page